# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In local,Code is working fine.I am able to consume the kafka message but in dev, getting an error saying

```
2020-01-21T10:49:48.373749251Z [21-01-2020 10:49:48.373] WARN  [] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
2020-01-21T10:49:48.433030131Z [21-01-2020 10:49:48.428] ERROR [] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
2020-01-21T10:49:48.433064831Z org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
2020-01-21T10:49:48.433071331Z Wrapped by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
2020-01-21T10:49:48.433076931Z  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
2020-01-21T10:49:48.433082131Z  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
```

Azure devops using as dev host

Code :

```
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> kafkaConfig = new HashMap<>();

        kafkaConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,config.getEwok().getBootstrapServers());
        kafkaConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "work");
        kafkaConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaConfig);
    }

@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }


@KafkaListener(topics = "attribute")
    public void consume(String message) {

       //Logic
    }
```

Could you suggest.Thank you

Comment: Possibly because the server requires SSL? I have seen such timeouts when the client/server do not have compatible SSL configuration.

Comment: @Gary Russell : By default security.protocol = PLAINTEXT. I am consuming the data from same broker in local as well as in dev. In local its working fine but in dev getting an error.In both place security.protocol = PLAINTEXT.

Comment: No ideas; then; sorry; I am not familiar with Azure. But it's likely some mis-configuration.

Comment: Please show your value for `config.getEwok().getBootstrapServers()`. And you just adjust the advertised listeners if you want to use Kafka off of a single machine